# Change User Priviliges From AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-ec2, admin, root

I'm very new to AWS. I've just started a new job where I've been passed on all the credentials from the guy I've taken over from. So I have root access to the AWS console account, but with the former employees user name and password. He's also set me up with ssh credentials for the EC2 instance.

My problem however is he didn't give me admin privileges for the EC2 instance. So when I SSH in and try to upload code changes I get permission denied. Is there some way I can change my privileges through the AWS console? Coming from Digital Ocean so I'm completely at a loss here on what way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS credentials control the management of AWS resources, such as the launching of EC2 instances. They aren't relevant at the OS level on a Linux (or Windows) instance. You may need to use [sudo](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/linux-commands-for-beginners-sudo/) to elevate your privileges on a Linux instance.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It gave me a starting point. My guy was contactable in the end and I requested sudo privilege from him. All good now.

Comment: Perhaps you could mark the best response as the answer, or simply write up your own response to your question and mark it as the chosen answer. That way people will know the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things could work here :

1. Since you have all the credentials passed from the guy, it should include the key-pair for the instances. So if you have that, you could ssh using it like,

> ssh -i "my-key-pair" ec2-user@ec2xxxxx.xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com

The default user, either 'ec2-user' or 'ubuntu', it has sudo privileges by default. Run following after logging in,

> sudo -i

You could then edit sudoers file to make necessary permissions.

2. You could take an ami of the current running instance and launch a copy. While launching, create a new key-pair. Rest action can be same as in Plan 1.